# Storing products in a MYSQL database and then search and filter them?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am tasked with building a searchable list for a friend of mine, I am mostly a front-end designer, so I only know extreme basics and whatever I can find through books and tutorials.

As for the question, is there a way to create items in MySQL database that could hold a few tags such as height, width, thickness, color, company, type, category and a profile image of it? In theory, I would like to set up a registration page, which I already have, that my friend could use to add products himself. Would creating the items as "items" in a "`product`s" be an effective way of going about this?

```
CREATE TABLE `admin`.`productss` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `type` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `category` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `thickness` CHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `height` CHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `color` CHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `material` CHAR(128) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Or does the syntax not allow me to do that?

I currently have a solution using a '*fake*' database, or like a long list that is hidden until searched, but this is done only using HTML, CSS, JS and I am looking for a more *elegant* solution to go about this.

===========================

Fiddle of the working filtering w/ HTML/CSS/JS:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/j1by6xn1/10/

Fiddle of the 'fake' database list:
http://jsfiddle.net/5ky8gx4L/

===========================

```
+----+-----+----+
|NAME|GREEN|15in|
+----+-----+----+
|NAME| RED |10in|
+----+-----+----+
```

And upon filtering by size '15in' it will only show the products with 15in as a size tag.

```
+----+-----+----+
|NAME|GREEN|15in|
+----+-----+----+
```

Comment: Show us what you're doing with the `fake` list and we can help build your query.

Comment: You should be fine. Avoid using [keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) for column names.

Comment: Let me create a fiddle and I'll edit my question, give me a few moments.

Comment: How did you come up with CHAR(128) !?!

Comment: I copy and pasted code from another sql database I made, and I repeated the 'password' and 'salt' for the sake of an example.
`password` CHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `salt` CHAR(128) NOT NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert rows into the table `productss` you showed, then you can filter them with the `WHERE` clause. This would go something among the lines of:

```
//This shows all the products with type 'My Type' :
SELECT * FROM `productss` WHERE `type` = 'My Type' 

//This shows all the products where the category has the text 'abc' in it (so also 12abc34 or 12abc :
SELECT * FROM `productss` WHERE `category` LIKE '%abc%'

//This shows all the products where the color is 255:
SELECT * FROM `productss` WHERE `color` = 255
```

This is for back-end filtering, the neat way to do it front-end is to use AJAX to call a PHP script from JavaScript with the variables it needs to filter.

Another way to do this is to use jQuery, print all the rows in a list and add data-something attributes; then your `li` tag will look something like:

```
<li data-color='255' data-category='Something' data-type='My Type'>Hello</li>
```

the values data-color, category etc. will come directly from your database. Then you can filter them like so:

```
$(function(){
  $(".sortButton").click(function(){
    var filterByColor = $(this).attr('colorfilter'); //say this value is the color you want to filter by
    $("li").hide(); //hide all options
    $("li[data-color="+filterByColor+"]").show(); //show the options that match the filter
  });
});
```

Comment: So if I had 2 products such as: a green, 15inch, 3mm thick, artsy glass piece  and another as the same, but with red. the clause 'WHERE' will filter based on what ever is listed? WHERE 'color' = Green, would show only the green one?

Comment: That is exactly the case. You can also give multiple WHERE statements with the AND operator like so: `SELECT * FROM productss WHERE color = 255 AND type = 'My Type' AND category LIKE '%something%'`

Comment: Is this for client side filtering or only back end? I am looking to allow the client to filter a list based off of buttons and drop downs. **added table to question for better understanding**

Comment: This is for back-end, i will change my answer to add the answer the reformed question

Comment: Ahh, I see now, this is a lot more elegant of a solution than the fake database we have in place. Excellent, marking as answered, thanks for the help!